# Silex Redirect with YAML

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, silex

In Symfony 2 I can :

```
root:
    pattern: /
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
        path: /login
        permanent: true
```

But I use silex (with YAML) so there is no `FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect`.

How can I make, in Silex, a simple route Redirect with YAML ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, Silex does not have such an option, but you can just return a redirect response from your / route (without yaml):

```
<?php
// your controller.php file or something similar
// ...
$app->get('/', function() use ($app) {
  // assuming you named your /login route 'login' here
  return new RedirectResponse($app['url_generator']->generate('login'), 301);
})
->bind('home');
```

If you insist on going the yaml route (you shouldn't, if you need FrameworkBundle, you should use Symfony instead of Silex) you can always create your own [RedirectController](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/RedirectController.php#L26) with a [urlRedirectMethod](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/RedirectController.php#L84) (be aware that resolving controller arguments won't work directly, this is one of the reasons I suggest you to use Symfony and don't reivent the wheel)

Comment: I was using silex because I was thinking that I could have more control on the code. But you are alright, more I progress and more I "recreate" Symphony native functions.. Thanks, your solution is ok for me.